# Excel swaps month & day in csv import

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, date

So, I download a csv from an analytics website. When I try to open on excel (or google sprd, open office, ...) the date is wrong.

01/01 -> 1st Jan (correct because is palindromic)
02/01 -> 1st Feb (instead 2nd Jan)
03/01 -> 1st Mar (instead 3rt Mar)

If I tried to change date format, it'll change the position.

How to fix this problem? (I'm using a mac)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I found this:

"Select column of Text dates you want to convert.
Click Data | Text to Columns….
Click Next to get to 3rd page of Wizard
Under "Column data format" choose "Date" and then click dropdown arrow
Choose format of Text you are converting from. ie:"DMY" for Day Month Year Month.
Click Finish"